# Are there any Schottky-diodes that can replace the ones on this PCB?

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, component-selection, schottky, replacement

I want help with finding Schottky-diodes to replace the ones on the PCB bordered in the red rectangle. They are probably non-working as they failed the continuity test with a multimeter. I have two DVD players pcbs. The first one is functioning well. The second one does not turn on. Only power indicator lit red.

Part of DVD player circuit board:

[image]

This board is workable and rarely used. Just presented here for readable data on components in the red rectangle. The photo of the first non working one is shown under my other question posted.

[image]
This board is unworkable.

Comment: How did they fail the continuity test?  All shorted or all open?  They don't look damaged.  There may be something connected in parallel that causes it to look like they are shorted.  There's an inductor to the right of the diodes.  If they are connected to it, then you might get a short circuit reading.

Comment: Specific part recommendations are considered off topic. Also you don't test diodes with a continuity tester, so you can't even be sure that they're bad. Also, how did you determine that they are schottky diodes and not just standard silicon rectifiers?

Comment: I'd rather suspect the soldering of that creatively soldered 0 ohm resistor on top of those SOT23 pads.

Comment: @Lundin Could it be a last minute change just before assembly?

Comment: It looks like SMD components has been soldered manually. The capacitor or varistor (?) near the top-right corner of the red square near the R120 mark, is not properly soldered and is most certainly not connected. Maybe the problem is from there. First I would re-solder this component and others bad soldered ones.

Comment: The beige capacitor, the 4th component from the lower side of the red square between the resistors reading 475 and 102 is also not properly soldered.

Comment: How do you know that they're Schottky diodes?  And based on their grouping, looks like they could be in a full-wave bridge rectifier circuit, for the power supply.

Comment: And yeah, on closer inspection the solder job is below mediocre. There's a cold joint on the SO8 too. You need a solder iron, a flux pen and ideally a microscope, then go through _everything_. After that, your problems could be gone.

Comment: The quality of components already soldered on the pcb is good enough to make the dvd player work flawlessly. You seem to forget the question I asked. The second photo is worth inspecting closer. Some holes like pores on each of diodes may tell of  flaws even deeper flaws.

Answer (score 6):

Any Schottky diode that will fit that has equal or greater voltage and current ratings will work in **most** applications. Without a circuit diagram and additional information 100% certainty is not possible.

**HOWEVER** continuity is NOT a suitable means of testing a diode.
You may mean "diode test" as implemented on many multimeters.
With the tester set to "diode test" a defined current is supplied and voltage drop across the device under test is established.
Forward voltage should be a diode drop (or less due to associated circuitry).
Reverse voltage should be set by associated circuitry.

The diode test position on multimeters is usually marked by a diode symbol.
You may also need to select a subrange.
The tester functionality can be checked with a bare known-good diode which should provided clear Vf and Vr typical of the device being tested.

If diodes or other "power" components fail the cause is usually in some other fault-location. Replacing faulty components without an understanding of the fault cause will often lead to repeat component failures and possibly additional damage elsewhere.